# PHP how to import class with namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, include

I have never used namespaces in PHP before and I cannot import some library classes that use them. I'm trying to use the [wsdl2php](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator) library, here is the example code on how to use the library:

```
$generator = new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator();
$generator->generate(
  new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Config(array(
    'inputFile' => 'input.wsdl',
    'outputDir' => '/tmp/output'
  ))
);
```

However, it doesnt matter where I put my php file that executes this code, it always throws class not found error, even if I include both classes with `include` or `require`, then the library class will throw class not found error, since it wants to use yet another library class.

Here is some directory tree for reference:

```
[src]
    [Filter]
        DefaultFilter.php
        ...
    [Wsdl2PhpGenerator]
        [Console]
            Applicaton.php
            ...
    ...
    Config.php
    Generator.php
    my_php_file_here.php
```

namespace declaration in Config.php: `namespace Wsdl2PhpGenerator;` How `use` is used in Config.php:  `use Wsdl2PhpGenerator\ConfigInterface;`

From what I have seen, I have added the following to the start of my php file:

```
namespace Wsdl2PhpGenerator;

use Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator;
use Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Config;
```

With no success, I still get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator' not found in C:\kajacx\programming\PHP\EET\test\wsdl2phpgenerator-master\src\kappa.php on line 8 ($generator = new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator();)
```

So, how to make this work?

Comment: You forgot the add a starting `\ ` before your namespace: `use \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator;` This `\ ` indicates that your namespace is outside of the current namespace scope

Comment: `namespace Wsdl2PhpGenerator;` is reserved for the upstream package you are using, you should not use it.  In your code, use your own namespaces eg `namespace kajacx`.  You will either need to use an autoloader or require the needed files yourself.  To make life easier, go ahead and check out composer: https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: @Timothy yes i have tried adding `\\` before the namespace, still i get the same error. @ymas I have used composer to get these files in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and composer will resolve the imports for you.
(tested with the same lib and it worked)

Answer (score 1):

as as I just worked with the wsdl2php lib (cloned from github) and had the same issue, here is what I did to resolve it :

1) don't forget to launch `composer install` before all ...

2) Add `require_once dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of your php file.